# Undoing a bad pull

Tags: git

First of all, Git sucks.  I know, I know, it's supposed to be the best thing since sliced bread, but it sucks.  It's like trying to shave with a chainsaw: one slight mistake and there are blood and teeth everywhere.  Perhaps, if I could actually make an exact distinction between a head, a ref, a commit, a branch, a stem, a gnargel, and a whizpoo, some of this might be a little easier but to an ordinary mortal with only 10 years experience of SVN, Perforce, and RCS, it all looks like rather cranky black magic.

Now for some reason, `git pull` has never worked for me.  I get a 10-line error message that has been, so far, about as helpful as the word "error".   Googling the error message produced a wide array of suggestions that only had in common the fact that they had no apparent affect whatsoever. But that's not today's problem: I've gotten used to typing `git pull origin branch`.

Today, I was flipping back and forth between two branches, "master" and "lounge" and at the moment I was in the master branch.  I wanted to get the latest changes from the remote repository to the local one, but I mistyped.  Instead of writing `git pull origin master`, I wrote `git pull origin lounge` and then, without thinking, typed in the correct command.

There's no evidence of the first (bad) pull in log, just two merges from the master:

```
commit 0c6be9569bab0581244ea8603bf2edfee82cdd7b
Merge: 43fdec5... db09f0d...
Author: Malvolio <info@xcompanyx.com>
Date:   Wed Nov 24 20:38:58 2010 -0500

Merge branch 'master' of github.com:xcompanyx/xRepositoryX

commit db09f0d79d744d6a354142041b47ff5d748999f3
Merge: 81b6c3d... fc73e25...
Author: Malvolio <info@xcompanyx.com>
Date:   Wed Nov 24 17:38:16 2010 -0800

Merge branch 'master' of github.com:xcompanyx/xRepositoryX

commit 81b6c3d04b7c464f8750a56282635526a5ef83a1
Author: Michael <info@xcompanyx.com>
Date:   Wed Nov 24 17:38:07 2010 -0800
    the last commit I did
```

But files newly created in the lounge branch are there in my repository.

So now I'm fscked, right?  Should I just torch my repository, clone the remote again, reapply all the unpushed changes manually, and chalk it up to Git sucking or is there some incantation I can recite that will make it all better?  Would it help if I sacrificed a goat?

Comment: @Robert - But then I wouldn't get such a nice laugh.

Comment: And, to the original problem, I decided to experiment with the possibility when it said "Merge branch 'master'" it really meant "Merged [some unknown and unnamed] branch [with the current branch, which, as you know, is named] 'master'".   I tried a hard reset back to 81b6. That seemed to work (although, oddly, the next pull from the origin retrieved some files changed much earlier) but as with all thing Git, I have to just cross my fingers.

Comment: I would love to try and help you, but you spent half your post attacking the SCM you're asking how to use, and neglected to actually provide enough information to answer your question. Do you actually want help, or just to rant?

Comment: It looks like one of your problems is that you're thinking of a pull as "retrieving files". It fetches and merges *commits*. Just look at the history (perhaps in `gitk`) and it should be clear enough why you see the content changes you do.

Comment: I should point out that 10 (or even 20) years of experience with *centralised* VCS like `svn` and `p4` (we'll ignore `rcs` - I'm feeling charitable) don't really help when using `git`. It's a different paradigm and requires you to know a different set of abstractions.

Comment: You have inspired me to write a neat tutorial on git!

Comment: @Jefromi -- I don't understand the difference (in context) between "fetch" and "retrieve" but if it's important... grrr.  @Noufal, yes, I have realized that although the *purpose* of svn and p4 is same as git's, the strategy is so differences that what familiarity I have is more a liability than a help.  @Lakshman, I look forward to reading it.

Comment: This question and answer was actually helpful to me. It's too bad it was closed and not simply edited.

Comment: The touchiness of some open-source people is always a source of (rather mean-spirited, I confess) amusement to me.  Six people closed as "unanswerable" a question that at least nine people upvoted and two people actually gave (almost identical and correct) answers to!

Comment: @Malvolio Try Mercurial, it is like Git only using it doesn't make you feel like you are being bullied by a nerd

Comment: Probably the worst thing about git is all the arrogant people who have wasted many hours of their life learning all the gibberish commands.

Comment: +1 For descriptive question. Of course it was closed by the git police. Git does feel like MS Word in terms of usability.

Comment: @Malvolio - yes, saying anything negative about `git` is a surefire way to have a question closed. Even if you hint that it or might not be 100 % perfect. The truth is `git` sucks, it sucks so hard you're left suspended in air from the force of the vacuum. What `git` forces you to do is a bad thing, very bad, very very bad.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. `git` is a perfect example of the crap that gets produced when you allow engineers with a trivial grasp on humanity design an interface. It sucks. It is, hands down, the worst-designed piece of software I've ever used. If the creators of `git` were to design an email client you'd have to peel a banana to send your email.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `git reflog` to see what your HEAD pointed to before you screwed it up.

You should see something like:

```
48ab8d HEAD@{0}: pull: Fast-forward
a34bda HEAD@{5}: commit: my last commit message
```

Now, point your master branch back at the commit before the bad pull:

`git reset --hard a34bda`

Done.  Like it never happened.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to investigate reflog more, but yes, "reset" definitely seemed to do the trick.  I'm still curious about the way it looks in the log, but the way it looks on the disk is correct.  And @Piskvor: I read it as re-flog the first time too.  What does that say about us?

Comment: `git reflog` is the command you use when `git` has beaten the soul out of you and you still haven't solved your problem. Just `git reflog` and enjoy another week of being bashed over the head by the tool that's supposed to make your life easier. It's really the only good nomenclature in the entire command set of this POS software. *"Thank you, Git! May I have another error!"*

Answer (score 6):

I can't totally understand your history from your question, but in general, if you make two merges (a pull is a merge), it is completely straightforward to remove one of them.

```
- o - o - o - A - M1 - M2 (master)
                 /    /
      - o - o - o    /   (origin/lounge)
                    /
             - o - o (origin/master)
```

The most obvious way:

```
 git checkout master
 git reset --hard A
 git merge origin/master
```

This uses your locally cached version of origin's master, if you want to merge whatever's out there now, use `git pull origin master`.